# On a system of equations in $\mathbb F_2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, finite-fields

**Input**: System of $\Omega(t)$ independent polynomials in $\mathbb F_2[x_1,\dots,x_{t}]$ of degree $O(t)$.

1. Can we output a common solution of the system in polynomial time?
2. Can we output parity of the number of common solutions of the system in polynomial time?

Comment: You can, but not always. Here is the question of solving a system of nonlinear algebraic equations. This problem has a separate issue - even for the second degree, the complexity of solutions increases greatly. And no one really needs them. Some solutions of private systems can be viewed there. https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046t281f3046_system_of_equations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1 - No, the problem is NP-hard even if degree of all polynomials is 2.

2 - See, for example, paper [Solving Systems of Polynomial Equations over
GF(2) by a Parity-Counting Self-Reduction](https://acris.aalto.fi/ws/portalfiles/portal/35681013/LIPIcs_ICALP_2019_26.pdf) by Björklund et al.